UI Stuck in time picker in ionic 6

Randomly Ui stuck in time picker.
When i am open time picker many times randomly stuck in 12 AM time and The time not displaying patched value or current time value.

Gif reference
Below is my html code:
  <ng-template>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-datetime [value]="selectedDate" #dateTimePicker [presentation]="presentation" [min]="minValue"
          [max]="maxValue" (ionChange)="onChange($event)"></ion-datetime>
          <ion-text (click)="dismiss()">Close</ion-text>
      </ion-row>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>

<section >
  <ion-input  [value]="displayValue"  [id]="triggerId" readonly></ion-input>
</section>


Below is my ts code:



@ViewChild(IonModal) modal: IonModal;

onChange($event) {
this.displayValue = // convert time stamp time event to AM/PM formate
}

  dismiss() {
    this.modal.dismiss();
  }

I tryed in ionic 6 and 7 but have randomly stucking in ion-datetime picker 12:00 AM.

Try with ion-datetime-button
ion-datetime-button ionic weblink

Thank you, By using ion-datetime-button working fine without any stuck, but i want solution using ion-datetime with ion-modal. Suggest me if have any other idea.
